# Uncaught RangeError jQuery Error

Tags: jquery

```
$(".other_option").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();

    if (selected == 46 || selected == 49) {
        $(this).parent().find(".js-register-field-other").slideDown();
    }

    if (selected !== '46' || selected !== '49') {
        $(this).parent().find(".js-register-field-other").hide();
    }
});
```

Couple of problems, the bottom expression always returns `true`, even if it's `false`. I'm also getting an error in the console:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: You mixed the compare types `== 46` and `!== '46'`    Integer and String compare

Comment: Can you give details on what you're trying to achieve. I can almost guarantee the second if statement logic is flawed. The error you describe seems unrelated to the code you've shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second condition is always true, because selected is always different from `'46'` OR `'49'`

`selected` can not be 2 different values at the same time.

I'm sure you need an AND compare.

```
if (selected !== '46' && selected !== '49') {
    $(this).parent().find(".js-register-field-other").hide();
}
```

In that case you can also write `else` instead of this condition.

But the ocoured error has nothing todo with the given code.